# Apache mod-jk returns 404

Tags: apache, tomcat7, mod-jk

I followed the instructions in [Apache 2.4 Tomcat7 and mod_jk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24202171/apache-2-4-tomcat7-and-mod-jk) with only the jk-manager and jk-status errors which Santosh said can be ignored in his answer to the above question.

My virtual host section:

```
JkMount /app/* ajp13_worker
```

and my workers.properties file:

```
worker.ajp13_worker.port=8009
worker.ajp13_worker.host=localhost
worker.ajp13_worker.type=ajp13
```

After restarting tomcat and apache, I can access http://localhost:8080/webapp/ but I got a 404 from http://localhost/app/webapp.  This 404 is from Tomcat (not Apache) so mod_jk has forwarded the request. But the 404 error page said

```
message: /app/webapp {NOTE: /app in front}
description: the requested resource is not available.
```

If I type http://localhost:8080/xyz the error page is like this:

```
message: /webapp/xyz {NOTE: NO /app in front}
description: the requested resource is not available.
```

If Tomcat sees a request for /app/webapp instead of /webapp, of course it cannot find the page, so is my configuration wrong?

Comment: OK now with a few resets.