# Please help in mod_jk/apache2/JBoss EAP 6.3

Tags: jboss6.x, mod-jk, apache2.2

I'm trying to use mod_jk for getting a result something like localhost/hello should display result as same as http://localhost:8081/hello

My next goal is LoadBalancing but I'm stuck with my 1st step because:

- localhost:8081/hello - works
- localhost/hello - Fails with 404 page cannot be found

To give overview of environment:

- JBoss 6.3.0 Alpha1
- Apache2
- mod_jk

I'm using domain and hostcontroller environment (not standalone). I have 2 JVMs in hostcontroller (TEST21 and TEST22). As of now my target is just to redirect all content of TEST21 jvm to localhost.
Let me try TEST22 part later.

I have edited apache2.conf, worker.properties, jk.conf.

Unfortunately I'm getting only 404 page cannot be displayed every time.

I did multiple restarts of all JVMs and Apache2 services. I did not see any errors in any logs.

I have attached all files and cross-posted the same question on jboss forum as well. It would help if you could refer to that link because I have too many files to add here.
https://developer.jboss.org/thread/269451

Comment: Are you on linux or windows?

Comment: Please copy paste mod_jk.log, your workers.properties and mod_jk.conf

Comment: Logs of mod_k.log
[Sat Apr 23 02:27:28.767 2016] [6039:3074886272] [info] init_jk::mod_jk.c (3365): mod_jk/1.2.37 initialized
[Sat Apr 23 02:27:28.767 2016] [6039:3074886272] [error] extension_fix::jk_uri_worker_map.c (564): Could not find worker with name 'jk-manager' in uri map post processing.
[Sat Apr 23 02:27:28.767 2016] [6039:3074886272] [error] extension_fix::jk_uri_worker_map.c (564): Could not find worker with name 'jk-status' in uri map post processing.
Remaining files at https://developer.jboss.org/thread/269451

Comment: You can fix this by reading this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24202171/apache-2-4-tomcat7-and-mod-jk

Comment: That helped! we are one step closer now. [Tue Apr 26 08:11:53.440 2016] [4855:3046107968] [error] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1630): (wlbTEST21) connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=111)..
So there is some problem in enabling 8009 at JBoss end :( But I really do not see it getting disabled at domain.xml..and netstat did not show 8009

Answer (score 0):

Configure your server.xml as following

```
<Connector port="8009" address="${jboss.bind.address}" protocol="AJP/1.3"
         emptySessionPath="true" enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" maxThreads="1000" connectionTimeout="60000000" />
```

Also make sure you set correct JVM Route in jboss-as/server/${profile}/deploy/jbossweb.sar/server.xml that looks like: `<Engine name="jboss.web" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="node1">`

Comment: Sorry again...I was able to successfully test in standalone-ha mode BUT same does not work in domain :(
May be I need to figure out diff between standalone.xml and domain.xml

Comment: So looks like it worked. We had to add AJP/1.3 in FULL profile. WE did that from admin console. Thanks much for showing me direction.